# Deflection of a cantilever beam composed of separate (not bonded) planks Uniform load

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, beam, deflection, shear

This is related to [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23612/deflection-of-a-cantilever-beam-composed-of-separate-not-bonded-planks)

It is the case of a simple cantilever beam having a uniform rectangular cross-section.

cantilever beam composed of separate planks - taken from [image: http://www.bu.edu/moss/mechanics-of-materials-bending-shear-stress/]

The question in the original post was **What happens if we split it along its longitudinal axis?**
[@sudhir](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/28221/sudheer-reddy-tenali) asked **What would happen if the beam was loaded uniformly**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original post the deflection of the coupled beam with the decoupled beam was

$$ \delta_{decoupled, concentrated} = 9 \delta_{coupled,concentrated}$$

If you change to a uniform load then with respect to the relative deflection of the coupled/decoupled would remain the same. i.e. $\delta_{decoupled, uniform} = 9 \delta_{coupled, uniform}$

Of course, the total deflection would be less because the formula for $\delta$ will change(see [link](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/solve-deflection-cantilever-uniform-load--boundary-condition-x-0-y-0-x-0-dy-dx-0-q5606113) ).

Assuming that the distributed load is $w=\frac{P}{l}$ (so that the total load is the same for comparison purposes:

$$\delta_{coupled, uniform} = \frac{w\cdot l^4}{4\cdot I_{coupled}}=\frac{P\cdot l^3}{4\cdot I_{coupled}} = \frac{3}{4} \delta_{coupled, concentrated}  $$